# Why is grep inversion not the same as negation in this case?

Tags: grep

My "test" file has 3 kinds of empty lines:

```
$ cat -nA test
     1  This is line 1 and it's followed by a blank line$
     2  $
     3  This is line 2 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 tab characters$
     4  ^I^I^I$
     5  This is line 3 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 whitespace characters$
     6     $
     7  This is line 4$
```

If I grep for the empty lines starting with the POSIX character classes "blank" or "space", I get the empty lines starting with tab or whitespace:

```
$ grep -n '^[[:blank:]]' test
4:          
6:   
$ grep -n '^[[:space:]]' test
4:          
6:
```

If I invert the search I get all the other lines:

```
$ grep -nv '^[[:blank:]]' test
1:This is line 1 and it's followed by a blank line
2:
3:This is line 2 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 tab characters
5:This is line 3 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 whitespace characters
7:This is line 4

$ grep -nv '^[[:space:]]' test
1:This is line 1 and it's followed by a blank line
2:
3:This is line 2 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 tab characters
5:This is line 3 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 whitespace characters
7:This is line 4
```

However, if I negate the search I get only the non-empty lines:

```
$ grep -n '^[^[:blank:]]' test
1:This is line 1 and it's followed by a blank line
3:This is line 2 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 tab characters
5:This is line 3 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 whitespace characters
7:This is line 4

$ grep -n '^[^[:space:]]' test
1:This is line 1 and it's followed by a blank line
3:This is line 2 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 tab characters
5:This is line 3 and it's followed by a 'blank' line with 3 whitespace characters
7:This is line 4
```

Why isn't negation the same as inversion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^[:space:]]` means “any character except those from `[:space:]` class”. Therefore the line matching `^[^[:space:]]` has to have at least one character.